# Django Mixin called twice and returns different responses

Tags: django, mixins

I've been strugglig with this bug for a week. I created a mixin `BaseMixin` to provide common data for two views `EmailView` and `PanelView`.

```
class BaseMixin(ContenxtMixin):
 
    def get_context_data(self, hash, **kwargs):
        context =  super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        try:
            ficha = self.get_ficha(hash)
            print("TRY")
        except Exception as e:
            print("EXCEPT")

       # more code

       return context

    def get_ficha(self, hash):
        pass
```

```
class EmailView(BaseMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = "app/cotador/cotacao_email_produtividade.html"

    def get_context_data(self, hash, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(hash, **kwargs)

        # more code

        return context
```

```
class PanelView(BaseMixin, TemplateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'next'
    template_name = "panel/proposta.html"

    def get_context_data(self, hash, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(hash, **kwargs)

        # more code

       return context
```

Whenever I call `EmailView` it calls the BaseMixin twice. First with the hash parameter, going into the try block and the second time lacking the hash and raising an exception. I noticed this behaviour by printing from within the try/except block:

```
TRY
INFO 2022-07-27 20:33:04,954 "GET /minhas-propostas/proposta/951c18b30ba2999860fa3324199d1272ae0275480b6453f54f90e348fe834bad HTTP/1.1" 200 92114

EXCEPT
ERROR 2022-07-27 20:33:06,200 Internal Server Error: /minhas-propostas/proposta/Roboto-Regular.ttf
```

And, I have no idea why, Roboto-Regular.ttf shows up in the url instead of the hash!!!

Then, when `PanelView` is called it works well with no errors and is called only once:

```
TRY
INFO 2022-07-27 20:44:34,664 "GET /cotacao-produtividade/print/487af3b7bf8e2615702ca662fe8746889750d67264e4ed10a8ada1e67f6ac9ed
```

I dont know how usefull it can be, but follow the `mro` for the classes.

EmailView

```
(<class 'agristamp.app.views.cotador.EmailView'>, <class 'agristamp.app.views.views.BaseMixin'>, <class 'django.views.generic.base.TemplateView'>, <class 'django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin'>, <class 'django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin'>, <class 'django.views.generic.base.View'>, <class 'object'>)
```

PanelView

```
(<class 'agristamp.app.views.panel.PanelView'>, <class 'agristamp.app.views.views.BaseMixin'>, <class 'django.views.generic.base.TemplateView'>, <class 'django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin'>, <class 'django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin'>, <class 'django.views.generic.base.View'>, <class 'object'>)
```

I apologize for the lack of clarity or information. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It looks like your `EmailView` is also triggered to fetch a font file, so something might be wrong in the `path`s that work as a "catch all".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you mean the url path? Here it is: `url(r'^minhas-propostas/proposta/(?P<hash>[0-9A-Za-z]+)', EmailView.as_view(), name='dashboard-proposta'),`